# Convert World Space GameObject Position to Screen Space Canvas UI Position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject that is in World Space. I also have UI GameObject that is in Canvas that is Screen Space that uses Camera.

How can I convert the position of World Space GameObject and assign it to the UI GameObject in Screen Space Canvas?

`WorldToScreenPoint` doesn't use help.

Comment: I need more spec information. What do you want on your project?

Comment: I want so that my UI GameObject in Canvas is positioned right were World Space GameObject is.

Answer (score 0):

camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position) should work.
**Keep in mind!** 0,0 is bottom left. So to position a UI element, you need to invert Y

To do that, you can do this:

```
Vector3 screenPos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
Vector3 uiPos = new Vector3(screenPos.x, Screen.height - screenPos.y, screenPos.z);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the most luck with the following:

```
uiObject.transform.position = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(Camera.main, worldObject.transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero));
```

Note the `worldObject.transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero)`. I find using the `worldObject.transform.position` directly often gives me an incorrect result.

Currently on Unity 2022.3.6f1